# Why does the summation symbol disappear?

Tags: summation, fourier-series, orthogonality, heat-equation, kronecker-delta

We know the orthogonality condition

$$\int_0^1\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)dx = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } n \neq m\\
\frac12 & \text{ if } n = m\\
\end{cases}
$$

From earlier in the text we had

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \int_0^1\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x) dx = \int_0^1 g(x)\sin(m\pi x) dx$$

which by the first line gives

$$A_n = 2\int_0^1g(x)\sin(n\pi x) dx.$$

The summation symbol disappears from in front of $A_n$ when arriving at the last line. I am hoping to learn why. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: The sum symbol doesn't disappears. What happens is that all but one summands are $0$, as explained in the previous lines.

Comment: I understand why this can be confusing for beginners. First look up the [Kronecker Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) and try to write the first line in terms of it. Then I'll explain in an answer.

Comment: By the way please write out the math in [MathJax using this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that people with screen readers can read it better.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is the same as

$$\int_0^1\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)dx = \frac12 \delta_{nm},$$

where $\delta$ is the [Kronecker Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). Now your second line is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \int_0^1\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x) dx = \int_0^1 g(x)\sin(m\pi x) dx$$

and becomes

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \frac12 \delta_{nm} = \int_0^1 g(x)\sin(m\pi x) dx$$

Since only the $n=m$ term on the left hand side is nonzero (by the definition of $\delta$), this is

$$A_m \frac12 = \int_0^1 g(x)\sin(m\pi x) dx.$$

Note that the solution was presented as

$$A_n = 2\int_0^1g(x)\sin(n\pi x) dx,$$

which has the index $m$ switched to $n$, causing some confusion for beginners. But all of our statements are true for all integer $n,m$, so changing the name of the index doesn't matter.